# Spring Security + Primefaces - can't handle viewexpiredeception

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, primefaces

I have problems with spring security and primefaces configuration. For my project, I needed the ability to log in, and it was decided to add spring security. Before I added the spring security, it was like this: if the user opens the page and is idle for half an hour, then the session dies, buttons on the page stop working and I get viewexpiredexception in the IDE's console when an button is pressed. Then I changed the web.xml and faces-config.xml files:

web.xml:

```
<!-- File(s) appended to a request for a URL that is not mapped to a web component -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>mypage.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>
        javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
    </exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location> <!-- type whatever suits your environment and requirements -->
</error-page>

<!-- Define the JSF servlet (manages the request processing life cycle for JavaServer Faces) -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map following files to the JSF servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

After that, if the session dies and the user presses any button, he will receive a message stating that the session has died and will be redirected to the page.

**Problem:** After I added spring security, it all stopped working. After half an hour of inactivity, the buttons stop working as before when I didn’t have the handler for viewexpiredexception, but there are no exceptions in the console and no redirecting, the user must refresh page himself. Here is my configuration:

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    // login
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
            .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error=true");
    http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/login.xhtml")
            .and()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/login.xhtml");

    // logout
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml");
    // not needed as JSF 2.2 is implicitly protected against CSRF
    http.csrf().disable();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john.doe")
            .password("{noop}1234").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("jane.doe").password("{noop}5678").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

}

I could not find how to solve my problem.

Comment: Might be spring-security interferes with the ajax calls of JSF/PrimeFaces...

Comment: It's likely that Spring Security catches the request and responds with code 403 because the user is not authorizedanymore to do anything on that view. Therefore rebuilding the view is unnecessary and view expiration exception won't be thrown.